# Style Seaborn and Plotly heatmaps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly, seaborn

I created a plot with Seaborn:

```
# imports
import random

%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create some random data
N = 20
rand_matrix = np.asarray([random.randrange(1,11)/10 for _ in range(1, N*N+1) ]).reshape(N,N)
data = np.flip(np.triu(rand_matrix), 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.date_range(start='2015-01-01', freq='MS',\ 
                  periods=N), columns = range(1,N+1))
df[1]=1

# seaborn plot
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
sns.heatmap(data = df,
            annot = True,
            vmin = 0.0,
            vmax = 1.0,
            cmap = 'PuBuGn')
```

[image]

Here is how I create the Plotly plot:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

data = [
    go.Heatmap(
        z=df.values,
        x=df.columns.tolist(),
        y=df.index.tolist()
    )
]

layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis = dict(ticks='', nticks=N),
    yaxis = dict(ticks='', nticks=N))

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

[image]

I have following questions:

- Seaborn: How do I change the y axis labels to YYYY-MM?
- Plotly: How do I get the older data to the top (like with Seaborn)
- Plotly: How do I get the data labels displayed in the heatmap (like Seaborn does).
- Plotly: I noticed that rendering is much slower than Seaborn. Can it be optimized, if yes how?

Comment: SO is more designed around a one-question-per-post model. Your first question has been answered many times already (under matplotlib tags), the second question is answered directly in Plotly's Axes docs under the header "Reversed Axes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2.** How do I get the older data to the top?

```
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
```

**3.** How do i get the data labels displayed in the heatmap?

```
ff.create_annotated_heatmap()
```

**4.** Can plotly be optimized?

No quick-fixes here.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Plotly:**

```
from plotly.offline import iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

#py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

data = [
    go.Heatmap(
        z=df.values,
        x=df.columns.tolist(),
        y=df.index.tolist()
    )
]

font_colors = ['white', 'black']
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z=df.values, colorscale='Jet', font_colors=font_colors)

fig.update_layout( yaxis = dict(ticks='', nticks=N))

# Make text size smaller
for i in range(len(fig.layout.annotations)):
    fig.layout.annotations[i].font.size = 8

# reverse scales
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")

fig.show()
```